# ‘There were no net reputation changes on this day’ with a non-zero reputation change

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, activity

Once, while idly browsing another user’s profile, I saw this:

[image: Dec 15 '20 (+3): There were no net reputation changes on this day]

Clearly this user has had some reputation changes on that day, but the software won’t allow me to see what they were from. Fair enough, but I think there are less confusing ways to phrase this.

Comment: Probably a one-in-a-million bug, or maybe this is because of private activity (i.e. things like post deletions don't appear there). Although if that was the case it probably wouldn't show it at all.